# Returning Row count in room database

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to display total number of rows stored in roomdatabase in kotlin. Below is what have tried so far:

**1. My dao (JobDao)**

```
    @Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Jobs_Table")
    suspend fun getAllJobsCount(): Int

    @Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Jobs_Table WHERE `Completion Status` = :status")
    fun getCompletedJobsCount(status: String = "Completed"): Int

    @Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Jobs_Table WHERE `Completion Status` = :status")
    fun getIncompleteJobsCount(status: String = "Incomplete"): Int

    @Query("SELECT SUM(Price) FROM Jobs_Table")
    fun totalToBePaid(): Int

    @Query("SELECT SUM(Price) FROM Jobs_Table WHERE Payment = :payment")
    fun totalPaid(payment: String = "Paid") : Int

    @Query("SELECT SUM(Price) FROM Jobs_Table WHERE Payment = :payment")
    fun totalPendingPayments(payment: String = "Pending Payment") : Int
```

**2. Repository:**

```
fun getAllJobCount(): Int = runBlocking{
        val count = async { jobDatabase.jobDao().getAllJobsCount()
        }
        count.start()
        count.await()
    }
```

**3. ViewModel:**

```
fun getAllJobCount(): Int{
        val count: Int = repository.getAllJobCount()
        return count
    }
```

**4.Activity**

```
private fun displaySummary() {
        jobTodo.setText(jobViewModel!!.getAllJobCount())
    }
```

**Error am getting:**
Process: com.droid.f.advancedjobmanager, PID: 7604
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.droid.f.advancedjobmanager/com.droid.f.advancedjobmanager.ui.SummaryActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2956)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3091)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1843)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6758)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:497)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:912)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.droid.f.advancedjobmanager.ui.SummaryActivity.displaySummary(SummaryActivity.kt:31)
at com.droid.f.advancedjobmanager.ui.SummaryActivity.onCreate(SummaryActivity.kt:27)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2933)

Comment: the issue is a null pointer error. I don't think you have properly created your view model.

Comment: Probably `jobViewModel` is `null`, and so `jobViewModel!!` crashes with a `NullPointerException`. It is possible that the issue is that `jobTodo` is `null`, but I would expect a slightly different error message in that case.